# Setting default action for new file extension

Tags: windows-registry, file-extension

I wanted to create my own file extension and set two actions possible to do with the file.

Here is .reg file I created:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dls\]
@="DLSource"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dls\ShellNew]
"FileName"="source.dls"
"NullFile"="source.dls"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\DLSource\shell\]


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\DLSource\shell\Open in DLI\command]
@="C:\\dl\\DLI.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\DLSource\DefaultIcon]
@="c:\\dl\\fav.ico"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\DLSource\shell\Compile with DLC\command]
@="C:\\dl\\DLC.exe \"%1\""
```

It works correctly, but `Compile with DLC` is default and is higher in context menu than `Open in DLI`. I want to set it oppositely, I suppose that now it's sorted alphabetical. 
Here is pic how it is now: [image: Now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dls]
@="DLSource"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dls\ShellNew]
"FileName"="source.dls"
"NullFile"="source.dls"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\DefaultIcon]
@="c:\\dl\\fav.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\shell]
@="OpeninDLI"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\shell\CompilewithDLC]
@="Compile with DLC"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\shell\CompilewithDLC\command]
@="C:\\dl\\DLC.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\shell\OpeninDLI]
@="Open in DLI"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\DLSource\shell\OpeninDLI\command]
@="C:\\dl\\DLI.exe \"%1\""
```

Don't use spaces in the `shell\commandname` keys. Instead of `shell\Compile with DLC` and `shell\Open in DLI` use `shell\CompilewithDLC` and `shell\OpeninDLI`, and set their **(Default)** values to the actual strings you want to display.

To specify the default action set the `ProgID\shell` key's **(Default)** value to the appropriate command sub-key. So in this case you need to set the **(Default)** value of `DLSource\shell` to `OpeninDLI`.

As an alternative to directly editing the registry consider using something like [**FileTypesMan**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) instead.